# How can I add horizontal scroll on multi select

Tags: css

I've a multiselect box with fixed width (we cannot change its width) and when I am increasing text in one of its option, text is cutting off.

Here is the fiddle - `jsfiddle.net/3aK82/`

I know adding word with no space is stupid thing but my QA assigned this bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<div id="container">
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
</div>

#container{ 
    width:100px;
    overflow-x: scroll
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/523tb/

Comment: Alexandros, can this be done without div?

Comment: I think no. Alternative you can use [choosen] http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ or [sexyCombo]: http://vladimir-k.blogspot.gr/2009/02/sexy-combo-jquery-plugin.html